# Combine multiple GAM models

Tags: generalized-additive-model

I have multiple GAM models (1000) done for my cross-validation. Now I would like to combine all of these models to an *average GAM model*, which would be the final model used for prediction. Is this possible and how could it be done?

The GAMs are made with mgcv package.

Thanks!

Comment: Could this be what you are looking for: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100245/how-to-summarize-gam-model-result-from-multiple-imputation-data-in-r?rq=1